# Нужно ли тире после конструкции с "когда"?

Tags: запятые, тире

> Когда я голоден(, -) я ем.

Подскажите, нужно использовать тире или запятую и почему?

Answer (score 2):

Чаще всего пишут всё-таки по правилам - с запятой, но и тире ошибкой не будет, потому что есть правило:

> При интонационном подчеркивании придаточные изъяснительные (дополнительные и подлежащные), реже условные  и  уступительные, стоящие впереди главного предложения, могут отделяться от
> него не запятой, а тире, например: *Буде спросит кто о чём – молчи…*
> (Пушкин); *Как он добрался сюда – уж этого никак не мог он понять*
> (Гоголь); *Что она натура честная – это мне ясно…* (Тургенев); *Пускай,
> как хотят, тиранят, пускай хоть кожу с живой снимут – я воли своей не
> отдам* (Салтыков-Щедрин); *Взгляну ли вдаль, взгляну ли на тебя – и в
> сердце свет какой-то загорится (Фет); Мне выслали какие-то книги, но
> какие именно – не знаю.*

У нас СПП с придаточным времени с оттенком условия (Если я голоден - я ем). Придаточное стоит перед главным. Если хочется выделить интонацией, тире в этом поможет.

Answer (score 2):

**Цитата:** "Чаще всего пишут всё-таки по правилам – с запятой, но и **тире ошибкой не будет".**

***Когда я голоден, я ем; когда я устал, я сплю.***

1. Эта проблема "**с  ошибкой, которой не будет**" меня почему-то всегда волновала, и вот что-то созвучное  с этим вопросом показалось  в содержании текста, откуда было взято предложение.

*Однажды Мастер Сутры пришел и задал вопрос Дзен Мастеру Дэ-Жу: «Я понимаю, что вы достигли Сатори. Что такое Дзен?» Дэ-Жу сказал: «Дзен — это очень легко. Это совсем не трудно. **Когда я голоден, я ем; когда я устал, я сплю.** Мастер Сутры сказал: «Это то же самое, что делают все люди. Тогда получается, что достичь Сатори и не достичь Сатори — это одно и то же».*

А объяснение было дано в конце, причем оно всего в одном слове: *Когда я голоден, я **только** ем. Когда я устал, я **только** сплю.* https://board.buddhist.ru/entry.php?b=915

Остальные же люди поступают не так: внешне они едят, а  внутри они думают, жаждут денег, славы, испытывают негативные эмоции. Разница велика, не правда ли?
https://board.buddhist.ru/entry.php?b=915

2. Вот и здесь примерно то же самое. Кажется, что нет разницы в том, что поставить, ведь ошибки не будет. Да только **знаки-то разные**, а вопрос был о том, как их выбрать. **По интуиции, как хочется**  —  такой  ответ?
3. У Розенталя это целая тема § 38. Тире в сложноподчиненном предложении http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=142#pp142

Тире  в СПП – это **неосновной** знак, он ставится «для **интонационного отделения** главной части СПП от придаточной». Это **авторское** решение.

**Интонационное деление** в представлении многих – это увеличенная **пауза**, но это не совсем так. При таком делении обязательно изменяется **расстановка ударений**, поэтому нужно видеть и слушать **весь текст**, а не часть предложения, взятую оттуда.

Вот в этом тексте параллельная интонация и, соответственно, **тире совершенно ни к чему.** В нем – спокойствие, и в нем никаких сильных эмоций, никакой экспрессии. Поэтому для этого текста **постановка тире будет ошибкой.**

4. **Итак, будет ошибкой или не будет ошибкой?** Да и что вообще считать ошибкой? Как известно, истинное суждение верно только в обозначенных пределах. Если, к примеру, взять школу, то могу ли я ставить тире в школьных сочинениях, где мне понравится и услышится? Нужно ли будет потом объясняться и называть хотя бы какую-то причину для этого? Я вот обозначил паузу... А зачем ты это сделал?

Но если эту фразу вы используете в Сети при беседе с друзьями, то вполне можно добавить **немного патетики и чувства,** тогда и тире можно поставить, обозначив интонационное деление.  В речи к каждой ситуации нужно подбирать **тонический рисунок**, подобно тому как художник подбирает краски (то сдержанную серо-голубую, а то и желто-красную).

Вот вроде бы и всё. И хотелось бы услышать **не только ваше молчание, но и ваше мнение тоже.** Хотя голосование за оппонента – это тоже своеобразое выражение мнения, но все-таки словами было бы понятнее.

Comment: Вы категорически считаете тире ошибкой? А  Вам скажут: "А у Лопатина" написано:  http://orthographia.ru/punctum.php?paragraph=pg124.php
"§ 124. В сложноподчиненном предложении может ставиться тире:
1) после придаточной части, стоящей перед главной частью (особенно при наличии слов это, вот, то в главной части): Когда тоска — хорошо писать (Пауст.)" Кстати, "то" и здесь можно подставить, хотя это не обязательно ("особенно при наличии..."). В правиле-то допускается. А откуда это предложение - никто не знает. Дано просто предложение, а кто как его произносил, это неизвестно.

Comment: Кстати, в приведённой Вами цитате тире очень даже возможно, там параллельные конструкции: Когда я голоден - я ем; когда я устал - я сплю. А спокойно мастер произносил или напряжённо - тоже неизвестно, в разных источниках может быть по-разному. Я считаю, тире здесь никак не ошибка. Но лучше всё-таки запятая - общепринятый знак, разделяющий простые предложения в СПП.